# python error when writing data in csv file

Tags: python

write a python program to write data in .csv file,but find that every item in the .csv has a "b'" before the content, and there are blank line, I do not know how to remove the blank lines; and some item in the .csv file are unrecognizable characters,such as "b'\xe7\xbe\x85\xe5\xb0\x91\xe5\x90\x9b'", because some data are in Chinese and Japanese, so I think maybe something wrong when writing these data in the .csv file.Please help me to solve the problem
the program is:

```
#write data in .csv file
def data_save_csv(type,data,id_name,header,since = None):
    #get the date when storage data
    date_storage()
    #create the data storage directory
    csv_parent_directory = os.path.join("dataset","csv",type,glovar.date)
    directory_create(csv_parent_directory)
    #write data in .csv
    if type == "group_members":
        csv_file_prefix = "gm"
    if since:
        csv_file_name = csv_file_prefix + "_" + since.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + "_" + time_storage() + id_name + ".csv"
    else:
        csv_file_name = csv_file_prefix + "_"  + time_storage() + "_" + id_name + ".csv"
    csv_file_directory = os.path.join(csv_parent_directory,csv_file_name)

    with open(csv_file_directory,'w') as csvfile:

        writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        #csv header
        writer.writerow(header)

        row = []
        for i in range(len(data)):
            for k in data[i].keys():
                row.append(str(data[i][k]).encode("utf-8"))
            writer.writerow(row)
            row = []
```

[the .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJxER.jpg)

Comment: using pycharm which use python 3.6

Comment: Because you are explicitly appending bytes to your row: `str(data[i][k]).encode("utf-8")` Just remove `encode`

Comment: You do `str(data[i][k])`.... what is this thing in `data[i][k]` that needs to be cast to a string?

Comment: @tdelaney well, whatever it is, it's converted to `bytes` right after. I assume it's a string... For example, those bytes *decoded* give '羅少君'

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - that's why i asked.

Comment: `for k in data[i].keys():` this isn't going to work consistently because dicts are unordered.

Comment: @tdelaney right, and it's better to use `for k in some_dict` if you want to iterate over keys anyway. But this just accuses the values, so a simple `row = list(data[i].values())` would work or `row = [str(v) for v in data[i].values()]` if the `str` cast is really necessary.

Comment: str(data[i][k]).encode("utf-8"),when remove the "encode", there is error:           File "C:\Python\PyCharmProject\FaceBookCrawl\data_storage.py", line 50, in data_save_csv
          writer.writerow(row)
          File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
      return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 17-19: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: try `open(csv_file_directory, 'w', encoding='utf8')`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga using `values` is certainly better but there is no need to cast to `str`. CSV does that. Better yet, use the `csv.DictWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems. The funky "b" thing happens because csv will cast data to a string before adding it to a column. When you did `str(data[i][k]).encode("utf-8")`, you got a `bytes` object and its string representation is `b"..."` and its filled with utf-8 encoded data. You should handle encoding when you open the file. In python 3, `open` opens a file with the encoding from `sys.getdefaultencoding()` but its a good idea to be explicit about what you want to write.

Next, there's nothing that says that two dicts will enumerate their keys in the same order. The `csv.DictWriter` class is built to pull data from dictionaries, so use it instead. In my example I assumed that `header` has the names of the keys you want. It could be that `header` is different, and in that case, you'll also need to pass in the actual dict key names you want.

Finally, you can just strip out empty dicts while you are writing the rows.

```
with open(csv_file_directory,'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=header, delimiter=',',
        quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(d for d in data if d)
```

Comment: and why there are blank lines,how to remove the blank lines

Comment: @bin You would get empty lines if some of the dictionaries didn't have anything in them. I filter out empty ones with `d for d in data if d`.

Comment: hi tdelaney,I modify program as you said,but in the csv file there are still unrecognizable characters such as à¸ˆà¸µà¹€à¸™à¸µà¸¢à¸£à¹Œà¸ª à¸­à¸²à¸£à¹Œà¹€à¸Šà¸­à¸£à¹Œ, and there are still blank lines

Comment: You may need a different encoding such as utf-16 or the data could be bad in the dict itself. Try to figure out which of the dicts in `data` is producing the odd data, print it, and post that in your post. As for the blank lines, is it every other line? What tool did you use to read it? My example (if you did `newline=''`) writes `\r\n` per line but that may confuse your reader. Do `print(open(csv_file_directory, 'rb').read(500))` to see what the line endings look like.

Comment: hi tdelaney, there is a item in data - id, it's a long number, but I find that in .csv file, this number is always missing the last digit, for example, the id should be 1030715900405221, but in the .csv file ,it's 103071590040522,misiing the last "1", the id number are all more than 10E15, a very long number, does it has some limit for the length of number in .csv file

Comment: I can't think of anything that would limit it. Maybe the tool you are reading it into? When I can't figure formats out I do `print(repr(open('filename', 'rb')))` to see if its a problem in the file or something that reads the file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like at least some of your issues have to do with incorrect unicode.

try implementing the snippet below into your existing code. As the comment say, the first part takes your input and converts it into utf-8.

The second bit will return your output in the expected format of ascii.

```
import codecs
import unicodedata

f = codecs.open('path/to/textfile.txt', mode='r',encoding='utf-8') #Take input and turn into unicode
    for line in f.readlines():
    line = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', line).encode('ascii', 'ignore'). #Ensure output is in ASCII
```

Comment: I interpreted the "unreadable" to mean that the text hadn't been converted back to ascii /humanreadable plain text

Comment: Right, but `ASCII` won't be able to handle all human readable text, and is rather limited, and the OP explicitly mentioned that they will need Chines and Japanese characters...